# What is the best practice way to send control signals back to the client from ajax request?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

When I send signals back to the client from an Ajax request, I use this form:

```
<!--a_b-->
```

so if some how I don't parse it, and it ends up in the html it won't break anything because it is a comment.

`a` and `b` denote values to convey information while `_` is a separator.

I can't but help wonder how others send "control" signals back from an ajax request.

What is the best way to send control signals from the server to the client using ajax?

Comment: Are you using a framework for AJAX or are you doing it in plain javascript?

Comment: @codeNinja - something that makes the client do something...so r in <!--r_b--> could initiate a reload for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would just use JSON.  Your client has to know how to interpret the response anyway, so encoding it in a html comment isn't really useful.  It just means you need extra work to parse later.  The `if some how I don't parse it` just means you have a bug you should fix.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely use a JSON package. There's no way for it to accidentally "end up in the html", so that shouldn't be a concern.

Receive the JSON response, check for your special properties (instructions), then respond accordingly with what was returned.

```
{ "reload": "http://www.google.com" }
```

Or

```
{ "alert": "HEY BUDDY!"}
```

Answer (score 1):

technically an ajax CALL should receive XML.
there is indeed a xhr.responseXML made for receiving such data.

You won't break anything...

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), it will just "do the work instead of you". A very simplified example:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://example.com/path?foo=bar',
    success: function(data) {
        // data won't land anywhere unless you want it to
    }
});
```

And how to encode your response? I would say don't think just go with JSON.
I see a benefit in returning JSON encoded objects (and not JSON encoded strings), because objects can easily be extended with new variables without breaking existing code, and it is practically no overhead.

So a typical response could look like dontGoPlastic said:

```
{"key":"value"}
```

Then in the browser, you can parse it and access "key" with:

```
var response = JSON.parse(data);
alert(response.key);
```